# How Parameter casting works in this program?

Tags: java

I have two sample program to understand parameter casting in Java.

Program 1:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestRunner r = new TestRunner();
        r.call(null);
     }

    void call(Object obj){
        System.out.println("I am from object");
    }
    void call(String obj){
        System.out.println("I am from string");
    }

 }
```

Program 2:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestRunner r = new TestRunner();
        r.call(null);
     }

    void call(Object obj){
        System.out.println("I am from object");
    }
    void call(String obj){
        System.out.println("I am from string");
    }

    void call(Integer obj){
        System.out.println("I am from Integer");
    }
 }
```

Program 1 prints "I am from string"
Program 2 giving compilation error.

Please Explain me how its work.

Comment: Duplicate! Duplicate! Just let me find it....

Comment: The most specific method gets called. In the first case `String` is more specific than `Object`, hence the `call(String)` gets called. In the second example `String` and `Integer` are equally specific, hence the compiler doesn´t know which method to call -> compiler error.

Comment: Oh! @Pshemo already did.

Comment: Try googling your problem using for instance query `java method ambiguous null site:stackoverflow.com`. You should find many answers on this subject.